# Why i'm getting on form1 Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Error   1   Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class

This is how the form1 top declared:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
```

Then i declared some variable as static:

```
private static FileInfo newest;
private static Stream mymem;
private static Bitmap ConvertedBmp;
private static Stopwatch sw;
```

I use this variables in form1 constructor:

```
ConvertedBmp = ConvertTo24(newest.FullName);
mymem = ToStream(ConvertedBmp, ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

The method ConvertTo24:

```
private static Bitmap ConvertTo24(string inputFileName)
        {
            sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            Bitmap bmpIn = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(inputFileName);
            Bitmap converted = new Bitmap(bmpIn.Width, bmpIn.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(converted))
            {
                g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
                g.DrawImageUnscaled(bmpIn, 0, 0);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            return converted;
        }
```

And the method ToStream:

```
public Stream ToStream(this Image image, ImageFormat formaw)
        {
            var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            image.Save(stream, formaw);
            stream.Position = 0;
            return stream;
        }
```

If i change anything to be not static i'm getting error on the method ToStream: Error   1   Extension method must be static

I tried to do anything static getting the error on Form1 when it's all not static i'm getting error on ToStream so it must be static method.

Comment: Extension methods must be static and be declared in a static class. Form1 in your example is not static.

Comment: Just move your extension method `ToStream` into separate static class and make this method static.

Comment: Why are you converting everything to static exactly? a static `Stream` seems strange to me especially..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you're using the [`this` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx) as first parameter in  `ToStream`:

```
public Stream ToStream(this Image image, ImageFormat formaw)
```

which is allowed only in extension methods. Remove it.

If you want to use it as [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)(which doesn't seem to be the case), the method must be sitting in a static class like this:

```
public static class MyDrawingExtensions
{
    public static Stream ToStream(this Image image, ImageFormat formaw)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then you could call it (also) in this way:

```
mymem = ConvertedBmp.ToStream(ImageFormat.Bmp);
```